# Plugin issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, url, model, plugin

I created an Plugin to change the category links from ?catId=xxx to the real category name. [image: this was before]

My Plugin look like this:

```
   class CategoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * Url
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
    ) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function afterGetUrl(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item $item,
        $resultUrl
    ) {
        //this code change the category links name to a freandly SEO Llinks
        if($item->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == "cat") {

            $return = $this->category->load($item->getValue())->getUrl();
            $request = $this->url->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);

            if(strpos($request,'?') !== false ) {
                $query_string = substr($request,strpos($request,'?'));
            } else {
                $query_string = '';
            }

            if(!empty($query_string)) {
                $return .= $query_string;
            }

            return $return;
        }

        return $resultUrl;
    }
}
```

When this code it's run, all the category has the same name, and it goes in the same link direction(the name and the location corespond with the first category name)

So now all my category have the same name as the first category.

If i try to modify  getUrl() function in vendor location(\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.php), everything works fine.

Does anyone know if the behaviour of the Plugin not allowed me do this thing? Or why the same function works fine in the vendor and in plugin not?

Comment: Please post a definition of this plugin from di.xml class

Comment: <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item">
        <plugin name="Medipoint-CartNotification-category-plugin" type="Medipoint\CartNotification\Plugin\CategoryPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>

Comment: sorry, was the wrong code posted, from the second try with the Preferances method. now i updated my code